# Accuracy for CMU Sphinx is very low when translating the audio

Tags: java, audio, cmusphinx

I try to use the following code to get the word result from the audio using Sphinx, however the accuracy is very low, may I know how to improve it?
Actually only the first three words are correct, the left 3 words cannot be detected correctly.

I have tested it using this voice https://www.dropbox.com/s/33fzzf5s59wbi7e/test2.wav?dl=0

```
 Configuration configuration = new Configuration();

// Set path to acoustic model.
configuration.setAcousticModelPath("resource:/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/en-us/en-us");
// Set path to dictionary.
configuration.setDictionaryPath("resource:/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/en-us/cmudict-en-us.dict");
// Set language model.
configuration.setLanguageModelPath("resource:/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/en-us/en-us.lm.bin");

StreamSpeechRecognizer recognizer;
try {
    recognizer = new StreamSpeechRecognizer(configuration);

    recognizer.startRecognition(new FileInputStream("1.wav"));
    SpeechResult result = recognizer.getResult();
    recognizer.stopRecognition();


    // Print utterance string without filler words.
    System.out.println(result.getHypothesis());

    System.out.println("================word result=============="+result.getWords().size());
    // Get individual words and their times.
    for (WordResult r : result.getWords()) {
        System.out.println(r);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Below is the output for the result:

```
15:50:34.677 INFO speedTracker         # ----------------------------- Timers----------------------------------------
15:50:34.677 INFO speedTracker         # Name               Count   CurTime   MinTime   MaxTime   AvgTime   TotTime   
15:50:34.678 INFO speedTracker         Compile              1       0.9860s   0.9860s   0.9860s   0.9860s   0.9860s   
15:50:34.678 INFO speedTracker         Load LM              1       0.8220s   0.8220s   0.8220s   0.8220s   0.8220s   
15:50:34.678 INFO speedTracker         Load Dictionary      1       0.1020s   0.1020s   0.1020s   0.1020s   0.1020s   
15:50:34.678 INFO speedTracker         Load AM              1       1.5760s   1.5760s   1.5760s   1.5760s   1.5760s   
15:50:41.150 INFO speedTracker            This  Time Audio: 1.41s  Proc: 6.40s  Speed: 4.54 X real time
15:50:41.152 INFO speedTracker            Total Time Audio: 1.41s  Proc: 6.40s 4.54 X real time
15:50:41.152 INFO memoryTracker           Mem  Total: 1181.50 Mb  Free: 726.20 Mb
15:50:41.152 INFO memoryTracker           Used: This: 455.30 Mb  Avg: 455.30 Mb  Max: 455.30 Mb
15:50:41.152 INFO trieNgramModel       LM Cache Size: 5646 Hits: 1215433 Misses: 5646
15:50:41.234 INFO speedTracker         # ----------------------------- Timers----------------------------------------
15:50:41.234 INFO speedTracker         # Name               Count   CurTime   MinTime   MaxTime   AvgTime   TotTime   
15:50:41.234 INFO speedTracker         Compile              1       0.9860s   0.9860s   0.9860s   0.9860s   0.9860s   
15:50:41.234 INFO speedTracker         Load LM              1       0.8220s   0.8220s   0.8220s   0.8220s   0.8220s   
15:50:41.234 INFO speedTracker         Load Dictionary      1       0.1020s   0.1020s   0.1020s   0.1020s   0.1020s   
15:50:41.234 INFO speedTracker         Score                318     0.0000s   0.0000s   0.0630s   0.0026s   0.8240s   
15:50:41.235 INFO speedTracker         Prune                1111    0.0000s   0.0000s   0.0070s   0.0001s   0.1440s   
15:50:41.235 INFO speedTracker         Grow                 1113    0.0000s   0.0000s   1.0780s   0.0049s   5.4790s   
15:50:41.235 INFO speedTracker         Frontend             161     0.0000s   0.0000s   0.0600s   0.0004s   0.0610s   
15:50:41.235 INFO speedTracker         Load AM              1       1.5760s   1.5760s   1.5760s   1.5760s   1.5760s   
15:50:41.235 INFO speedTracker            Total Time Audio: 1.41s  Proc: 6.40s 4.54 X real time
15:50:41.235 INFO memoryTracker           Mem  Total: 1181.50 Mb  Free: 726.20 Mb
15:50:41.235 INFO memoryTracker           Used: This: 455.30 Mb  Avg: 455.30 Mb  Max: 455.30 Mb
and you want slurring
================word result==============5
{and, 0.999, [140:670]}
{<sil>, 0.999, [680:780]}
{you, 1.000, [790:890]}
{want, 1.000, [900:1080]}
{slurring, 1.000, [1090:1590]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Default CMUSphinx model is trained on US English data, your pronunciation has quite strong accent. If you want to recognize your accent better you can adapt the model as described in tutorial

http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialadapt

The more data you will use for adaptation, the better accuracy will be.